# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: java, классы

В приложении есть активити `MainActivity` и его дочерний класс `Orders`.
В дочернем классе есть есть два метода. Первый делает видимым всплывающее окно, другой делает все наоборот. 
В main классе, в методе `onCreate()` я создаю объект класса:

```
orders = new Orders();
```

Далее кидаю слушателей:

```
findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        orders.openOrders();
    }
});

findViewById(R.id.orderListMainLayout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        orders.closeOrders();
    }
});
```

В итоге приложения крашится, а в Logcat я получаю следующее:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
    at truck.game.rpg.MainActivity$Orders.openOrders(MainActivity.java:107)
    at truck.game.rpg.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:57)
```

Вот как организован дочерний класс `Orders`:

```
public class Orders extends MainActivity {

    public void openOrders() {
        findViewById(R.id.orderListMainLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void closeOrders() {
        findViewById(R.id.orderListMainLayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Созданием activity должна заниматься ОС (обычно через метод `startActivity()`), вы не можете сделать orders = new Orders(); и ожидать, что оно будет работать как обычная activity. [Activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities?hl=ru)

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon здесь нет необходимости переходить на новую активити. В данной реализации я хотел создать окно, которое накладывается на MainActivity. А класс Orders взаимодействует с ним. Например открывает и закрывает это окно путем изменения setVisibility

Answer (score 0):

Ошибку я исправил. Дело было в том, что дочернему классу я унаследовал `MainActivity` и когда я оставил `public class Orders` мой код сработал. Вероятнее всего ошибка вызвана тем, что класс наследовал `Activity`, хотя активити он не являлся и планировался просто дочерним классом.